# Bulk setting Symfony form field values with setData in SF4.4

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-4.4

In my Symfony 4.4 application I have the following code inside my controller. I am attempting to pre-populate the form based on previous submissions or data pulled from the database. Importantly, the `DetailsType` form includes multiple entities so it's not a clean 1 entity per form setup here.

```
    $postVars = $request->request->all();

    $formData = [];
    if (count($postVars) > 0) {
        $formData = $postVars['crmbundle_register_details'];
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(DetailsType::class, $formData, [
        'attr' => ['class' => 'reCaptchaForm'],
    ]);

    $form->setData([
        'firstname' => $person->getFirstname(),
        'lastname' => $person->getLastname(),
        'email' => $person->getEmail(),
        'country' => $person->getCountry(),
        'timezone' => $person->getTimezone()
    ]);
```

My problem is if I try to pre-populate the form with `setData` above it does not work.

If I do it individually as below it works, but I can't see why. I'd prefer to pass `setData` an array rather than call `setData` multiple times.

```
    $form->get('firstname')->setData($user->getFirstname());
    $form->get('lastname')->setData($user->getLastname());
    $form->get('email')->setData($user->getEmail());
    $form->get('country')->setData($user->getCountry());
    $form->get('timezone')->setData($user->getTimezone());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form contains many entities, it's better to have an [embed form](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/embedded.html) for each entity. In this case, you don't need to call the setters at all. The controller action code will be:

```
$form = $this->createForm(DetailsType::class, $someParentEntity, [
    'attr' => ['class' => 'reCaptchaForm'],
]);
$form->handleRequest($request);
```